# How can I apply to a same career fair more than one time with same user in jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, httprequest, load-testing

I am doing load tests to a apply option of career fair section. But I have only one user's login informations and I want to do apply tests more than one time with same user. For example when I create 10 users with Thread Group, the http request for apply is going to be fall 9 times. I think that's why we use only one user and the apply button is going to be applied button and not clickable. How can I do this test?

Comment: Simulating the same user to apply multiple times in parallel doesn't sound like the typical load test for a public system - I'd rather expect multiple users to try working in parallel. Make sure you test what you actually want to test, and not what requires less data to be kept track of.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am an intern and the company gave me only one user's login informations. I don't know the right way to do this test, I searched for it over internet but I didn't found any useful solution.

Comment: Well, then they asked you to load test a (assumed by me) largely irrelevant scenario. My practice: For Load-Test I just enumerate users and their passwords - e.g. user1/password1 (or even have the same password for them all). And if the application doesn't accept the same user over and over again, you can stop right there. Unless your test is that a single user can only log in once. I'd not consider that a load test though, but a functional test.

Comment: My test is about the apply function, how many users can apply at the same time? For example for login test I gave only one user's username and password and then I created 1000 samples of that user with Thread group. It gave me the result if 1000 user's can login at the same time in 10 seconds. I want to test the apply function like login. But I don't know how to do that with only one user's login informations, because the apply button is going to be applied label after one sample and the other samples are going to gave errors. How can I do that test with only one user informations?

Answer (score 0):

There is one golden rule: 1 virtual user == 1 real user with all its stuff like credentials, permissions, business actions, cookies, cache, etc. See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for more details.

1. So ideally you need to have as many credentials as threads (virtual users) you set in JMeter's [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Test need to be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability), to wit leave the system in unmodified state so you could re-run the test once again. If the application process is irreversible you need to either cancel the application somewhere in the [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) or modify the database using [JDBC Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) to restore the system state

If your system doesn't allow multiple logins from one user I don't think you will be able to conduct your test with a single user for multiple sessions.